# 正規表現でURL文字列の最初と最後を削除したい

Tags: python, python3

python3で

```
https://hoge1.hoge2
```

のような文字列から

`https://`と`hoge2`を取り除き
`hoge1`だけを取り出す方法を教えていただけませんか

Comment: `hoge1` / `hoge2` それぞれについて、`.` が含まれる可能性はありますか？

Comment: 質問文から察するに「URLの最初と最後を」とした方が良さそうな気もします。

Answer (score 4):

「URLからサブドメインを取得する」が質問に対するゴールと解釈して答えます。

URLから何かしらの情報を得たいのであれば、まずは `urllib.parse` を利用しましょう（正規表現を使った解法は他の方に任せます）

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('https://hoge1.hoge2')
>>> print(o.hostname.split('.')[0])
'hoge'
```

ちなみに、より正確にドメインとサブドメインを取得したい場合は tldextract というパッケージを利用する方法もあります。
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract

Answer (score 0):

正規表現を使うなら

```
(?<=https:\/\/)\w+(?=\.\w+)
```

このパターンでhoge1にマッチします。
`(?<=)`はLookbehind, 後読み。このカッコ内パターンの後に来る場合のみマッチ。
`(?=)`はLookahead, 先読み。このカッコ内のパターンの前に来る場合のみマッチ。
なので`https:\/\/`（スラッシュはエスケープします）をLookbehindに、
`\.\w+`（ドットをエスケープ\wはアルファベットです、この場合は.hoge2にマッチ）をLookaheadに指定し、
その二つに挟まれた`\w`（アルファベット）を取り出します。